# Why am I unable to run the .login() attribute for robin_stocks?

Tags: python, api, authentication, attributes, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to import data from Robinhood through robin_stocks. I was able to import the package, but when I try to use the .login() attribute, it returns this error message in the Jupyter Notebook: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDSOn.png)

module 'robin_stocks' has no attribute 'login'

I'm certain that robin_stocks does, indeed have the attribute that Python is telling me doesn't exist. Where did I go wrong here?

I'm relatively new to programming, but usually I can find an answer to my questions pretty quickly on StackOverflow or any other resource. I can't seem to figure this one out, though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error when upgrading from 1.7.x to 2.0.3

I was able to solve this by changing the import from:

`import robin_stocks as rs`

To:

`import robin_stocks.robinhood as rs`

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the package that you are using. I actually had the same issue when I migrated to a new laptop and installed packages again. I turned out that a newer robin-stocks python package got installed and resulted in an attribute error for my previously functioning code. When I reverted back to the older version of the package (1.5.5) my code worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Bro, we can't guess what you has typed in your code, please link it to us.
But if you have some issues with basic method of module, i think some  thing gone wrong with import

Comment: I just edited the comment to include the code, although I don't think that's going to help much because I addressed the issue being an attribute/method that I know exists and have seen on others' code.